# Q: SQL: INSERT/UPDATE how to insert the value of the COUNT into the table?

Tags: sql, count, oledb

i want to count all ones(1) in the field1 and insert the counted value into a different table.
i am new to programming and i cant understand the error.

```
    If Not cnn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
        cnn.Open()
    End If
    Dim strSQL As String = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM VOTED WHERE field1 = 1" 'Create new connection'
    Dim CMD As New OleDbCommand(strSQL, cnn) 'Create new command'
    Dim DR As OleDbDataReader
    DR = CMD.ExecuteReader() 'Populate the reader'
    While (DR.Read())
        Dim cmd1 As New OleDbCommand
        cmd1.connection = cnn
        cmd1.CommandText = "UPDATE CandidateDB " & _
                            " SET VoteCount=" & DR(0).ToString() & _
                            " WHERE CandidateID=" & 1
        cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery()
        'MessageBox.Show(DR(0).ToString()) 'Show the result of the query'
```

ExecuteNonQuery: No value given for one or more required parameters.

i tried

executescalar: No value given for one or more required parameters.

Comment: did you assign the connection string to the connection before opening it?

Comment: i set the connection and it worked. but i have a new error. it says No value given for one or more required parameters. does my command at
    " SET VoteCount=" & DR(0).ToString() & _ is correct? or is there a code how will i get the value of the count value?
thank you for the quick response\

Comment: The please open a **new** question.

Comment: how to open a new question here?

Answer (score 0):

Just like the error message says, you'll have to set the Connection property on your command object cmd1 before invoking `ExecuteNonQuery`:

```
cmd1.Connection = cnn
```

Comment: I did what you suggested and it worked. And a new error showed up. No value given for one or more required parameters.